# My app cannot be installed in phones with Marshmallow and below

Tags: java, android

I just developed my quiz app in android studio. I generated the signed APK and shared with my friends, but it can only install in Android 7 supported phones and cannot install in phones with  android 6 and below.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the API level in build.gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `build.gradle` for `minSdkVersion`. And set it accordingly as mentioned [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers).

Answer (score -2):

The issue is that you developed the app to fit with android 7 and higher versions so you need to set the minSdkVersion to a fit with previous versions, I generally use 19.

You should check that you use support libraries also other wise it may cause you some bugs in different versions of Android.